# Checking my understanding of interior points

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm working on a proof regarding open sets. In that proof, I make an argument like this : Lets assume the intersection of two open sets ( $A_1$ and $A_2$ ) $L$ is not open. This means there exists a point $x_0 \in L$, such that $$B(x_0,\epsilon)\notin L$$

Because, for $L$ to be open, each $x_0 \in L$ must be the center of a ball with radius $\epsilon$. This would mean there exists an $\epsilon >0$, which increases the radius of some $x_0$ outside of the open interval $A_1$ or$A_2$. Since the radius of some $B(x_0,\epsilon)$ is outside of an open interval, this means there exists an $x_0 \in A_1/A_2$ located precisely at the end point of the interval ( e.g, if our interval was $(1,0)$ $x_0$ might be at $1$ ), which contradicts the fact that $A$ is open. Is this analysis correct?

Comment: It should be "such that $B(x_0,\epsilon)\not\subset L$" and this condition should hold for all $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: 'precisely at the endpoint of an interval' makes sense in the reals, but there are a lot of other topologies out there. You're broadly on the right track, but you should formalize it more directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, and if you want to show $A_1 \cap A_2$ is open, the direct proof is much easier: let $x_0 \in A_1 \cap A_2$. As $x_0 \in A_1$, there is an $r_1>0$ such that $B(x_0, r_1) \subseteq A_1$ and also $x_0 \in A_2$, there is an $r_2>0$ such that $B(x_0, r_2) \subseteq A_2$. Then define $r_3 = \min(r_1,r_2)>0$ and note that $B(x_0, r_3) \subseteq A_1 \cap A_2$ and you're done.